# Want To Convert Contact Type To String

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }
```

It Is The Actual Code Which Is Returning List Of **Users In Logcat**
I Want To Show That In Android Screen With **ListView**

Help me In This

I Created ListView In XML

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this.

---

I assume Contact is a custom class of yours, implement the toString() method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Id: " + getID() + " ,Name: " + getName() + " ,Phone: " + getPhoneNumber();
}
```

And then use:

```
ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(Eventually you should change the way the text is presented by using a custom layout instead of the built-in `simple_list_item_1.xml`.)

---

If `db.getAllContacts();` turns a Cursor into `List<Contact>` consider skipping this step and using a SimpleCursorAdapter instead.